# python search replace using wildcards

Tags: python, regex, search, replace, wildcard

somewhat confused.. but trying to do a search/repace using wildcards

if i have something like:

```
 <blah.... ssf  ff>
 <bl.... ssf     dfggg   ff>
 <b.... ssf      ghhjj fhf>
```

and i want to replace all of the above strings with say,

```
 <hh  >t
```

any thoughts/comments on how this can be accomplished?

thanks

update (thanks for the comments!)

i'm missing something...

my initial sample text are:

```
Soo Choi</span>LONGEDITBOX">Apryl Berney 
Soo Choi</span>LONGEDITBOX">Joel Franks 
Joel Franks</span>GEDITBOX">Alexander Yamato
```

and i'm trying to get

```
Soo Choi foo Apryl Berney 
Soo Choi foo Joel Franks 
Joel Franks foo Alexander Yamato
```

i've tried derivations of

```
name=re.sub("</s[^>]*\">"," foo ",name)
```

but i'm missing something...

thoughts...  thanks

Comment: hmmm...

missing something...

my initial sample text are:
  Soo Choi</span>LONGEDITBOX">Apryl Berney
  Soo Choi</span>LONGEDITBOX">Joel Franks
  Joel Franks</span>GEDITBOX">Alexander Yamato

and i'm trying to get

    Soo Choi foo Apryl Berney
    Soo Choi foo Joel Franks
    Joel Franks foo Alexander Yamato

i've tried derivations of 

    name=re.sub("</s[^>]*\">"," foo ",name)

but i'm missing something...

thoughts...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the rather usable Python [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) manual [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html), or for a more hands-on approach a [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/) section *5.2 Search and Replace*.

Comment: Regex is the easy way here. `s/<[^>]*>/<hh >t/g`

Answer (score 3):

How about like this, with regex

```
import re

YOURTEXT=re.sub("<b[^>]*>","<hh >t",YOURTEXT)
```

Answer (score 0):

don't have to use regex

```
for line in open("file"):
    if "<" in line and ">" in line:
        s=line.rstrip().split(">")
        for n,i in enumerate(s):
            if "<" in i:
                ind=i.find("<")
                s[n]=i[:ind] +"<hh "
        print '>t'.join(s)
```

output

```
$ cat file
blah  <blah.... ssf  ff> blah
blah <bl.... ssf     dfggg   ff>  blah <bl.... ssf     dfggg   ff>
blah <b.... ssf      ghhjj fhf>

$ ./python.py
blah  <hh >t blah
blah <hh >t  blah <hh >t
blah <hh >t
```

Comment: This is a good quick and dirty solution, but also not very extensible because of that; it also does not check the `b` after the `<` - although it is not clear whether that was a requirement by the OP. With regex he will have a much more versatile tool in his hands.

Comment: yes, i agree. without much other info from OP. also, if OP is really parsing complect HTML(or XML?), even regex is advised not to be used :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the "re" module, here's a little sample function for you although you could just use the one re.sub() line.

Use the "re" module, a simple re.sub should do the trick:

```
import re

def subit(msg):
    # Use the below if the string is multiline
    # subbed = re.compile("(<.*?>)" re.DOTALL).sub("(<hh  >t", msg)
    subbed = re.sub("(<.*?>)", "<hh  >t", msg)
    return subbed

# Your messages bundled into a list
msgs = ["blah  <blah.... ssf  ff> blah",
        "blah <bl.... ssf     dfggg   ff>  blah <bl.... ssf     dfggg   ff>",
        "blah <b.... ssf      ghhjj fhf>"]

# Iterate the messages and print the substitution results
for msg in msgs:
    print subit(msg)
```

I would suggest taking a look at the docs for the "re" module, it is well documented and might help you achieve more accurate text manipulation/replacement.

Comment: do you use functions for everything?